# Is it legal to convert a png logo of a company you're partnering with and convert it to a SVG file for them to use it on an application we made?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

Is it legal to convert a png logo of a company you're partnering with and convert it to a SVG file for them to use it on an application we made? I am thinking there's a general license that forbids you from doing this. Do I have to send an email to all of them asking them to provide a SVG file, which would be tedious, or is it considered to be fair-use since the company is working with us to provide their API in our applications to our clients? Assume the company is in the United States.

Comment: When it comes to IP rights, then almost everything is legal if you get permission from the IP owner.

Answer (score 3):

Bringing *fair use* into this sounds iffy if you are *partnering* -- that is a commercial relationship which should be defined.

If they did send you a file with their logo for a specific purpose, you can assume that you are allowed to use it **for that specific purpose.** If they did not send you the file, you can assume that they did not give you permission, or they would have included the file ...

Answer (score 1):

Converting the file means nothing.  It's the **use** of the file that would be problematic.  If you are using their logo in any way (including printing it out and taping it to a piece of paper) with a third party, you need their permission.

Comment: -1 his is not correct, converting the file is probably the making of a **derivative work** and so that needs permission on its own. But the use also requires permission of some sort.

Comment: Conveting the file on its own is might be a derivative work but who would know?

Comment: Perhaps no one, but the question was "Is it legal?" not "Will I be caught?"

Answer (score 1):

If you are partnering with them, you probably have implied consent to carry out acts within the foreseen scope of the partnership on their behalf.

It would be better to have a provision of the agreement in writing that says so, but it is hard to imagine them bringing a copyright infringement suit against a company they are working with that used the logo in connection with the joint enterprise without clearly prohibiting this conduct.